# Is this exterior algebra?

Tags: exterior-algebra

I'm learning algebraic topics like exterior algebra and Clifford algebra. I'm trying to understand exterior algebra now or more specifically - different constructions of it. I like the abstract definition of exterior algebra (and other algebras) via *universal property*. I've seen perhaps 4 different constructions of exterior algebra (including 2 that I, you can say, made up myself) and it made me to start wondering wether I can always define

$$v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_k:=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_k}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\cdot \ldots \cdot v_{\sigma(k)}$$

for $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ in some algebra $A$ with some multiplication $\cdot$? By $\cdot$ I mean here some arbitrary algebra multiplication (say: square matrices with matrix multiplication) not necessarily tensor product $\otimes$ of a tensor algebra. Will $A$ with thus defined $\wedge$ multiplication be the exterior algebra of $A$?

Comment: One issue is that your operation is not defined over arbitrary fields; it requires characterisitic at least $n!$ where $n$ is the dimension of your vector space. Essentially what you're doing here is trying to embed alternating tensors in $A$ and then identify those alternating tensors with the exterior algebra, but these aren't really the same thing unless your characteristic is 0.

Comment: The "correct" definition of the exterior algebra is as a *quotient* of the tensor algebra, not a subspace of it.  See Definition 3.1 and Section 10 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Remember that the elements

$$
v_1\land...\land v_k
$$

are supposed to generate the exterior algebra. Your elements however will at most generate a subspace of  $A$. This won't be isomorphic to the exterior algebra due to the problems with dimension. Of course there are some trivial cases where they do end up aligning.

Comment: In particular, if $A$ is commutative then the supposed exterior product is always $0$.